# Div not appearing on top of embedded Flash player

Tags: css, html, flash

I am trying to have the following div

```
<div style="position:absolute;width:1000px;height:25px;border:0px;solid #000;color:#052B8B"/>
```

appear over this object

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="900" height="700" id="Kirchhoff" align="middle"/>
<param name="movie" value="Kirchoff.swf"/>
<param name="quality" value="high"/>
<param name="wmode" value="opaque"/>
<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff"/>
<embed src="Kirchhoff.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#DDB85F" width="900" height="700" name="Kirchhoff" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" wmode="opaque"/>
```

I have tried everything with no luck. Thanks in advance.

Comment: by popping over i mean appearing on top.

Comment: you need to post the complete HTML code so we can see the relation between the two elements, plus ALL relevant CSS

Comment: @Johannes just uploaded it

Comment: are you aware that you can edit the question? (i.e. not add additional information as an answer)

Comment: no additional CSS?

Comment: Your DIV has no closing tag - the `<object>` tag will (depending on the browsers automatic error coorection) be *inside* the DIV....

Comment: my bad @Johannes first time here. no that is all what would you sugest?

Comment: before you don't fix that, there's no use trying anything else

Comment: @Johannes where is the mistake sorry? and thanks for your help

Comment: a DIV tag like `<div>` has to be followed by a closing tag like `</div>`. If the closing tag is missing, the browser will add it by itself (if you are lucky), but most likely not where you intend it to be. So just add it...

Comment: ...although all the HTML and CSS code would be needed to give you a definitive answer, try adding z-index:9999 on the div and see if that works.

Comment: did not work, i had also tried the wmode on the javascript set as opaque with no luck

Comment: Have you tried on old InternetExplorer? if you are using IE, you can try to display a same size iframe of div behind div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/ecn65bdv/3/

```
<div style="position:absolute;width:1000px;height:25px;border:0px;solid #000;color:#052B8B">This is div</div>
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="900" height="700" id="Kirchhoff" align="middle">
<param name="movie" value="Kirchoff.swf">
<param name="quality" value="high">
<param name="wmode" value="opaque">
<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff">
<embed src="Kirchhoff.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#DDB85F" width="900" height="700" name="Kirchhoff" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" wmode="opaque" />
```

Your object html is messed up.  Your doing one object, but in your HTML you provided your suggesting you have an object tag and a seperate embed tag.  Your div end tag is also messed up.  See my fiddle.  z-index did infact bring the div tag in front of the object.

Comment: Thank you very much this solve my problem! Just one small question the div is now like 2 px under the object so the top part can be seen and I can seem to adjust the borders what do you recommend?

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer!  When you say 'under' I assume you mean that the div tag is 'below' the object.  To adjust the position of the div you can add the following css to the div:  Position:absolute;top:2px;.  Or you can do Position:relative; depending on your needs. To adjust the top borders you can do this css:  border-top:none;  Details can be found at:  https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp.  I also noticed that you have invalid css for the div tag:  border:0px;solid #000;.  It should be:  border:0px solid #000;

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `z-index:[value]` to it.

Comment: i tried and still no luck the dir always stays behind

Answer (score 0):

Your inline CSS on that DIV is a mess (or do you really want that DIV to be only 25px high - if yes, change that in the code below - I assume you want to cover the object completely)...

I erased it, assigned class `x` to that DIV and set up a CSS rule for it that has the same width and height as the `object` tag. (Different background color green)

Also note the `margin: 0` on  `body`which prevents the default margins.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.x {
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  width: 900px;
  height: 700px;
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="#052B8B">
  <div class="x"></div>
  <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="900" height="700" id="Kirchhoff" align="middle" />
  <param name="movie" value="Kirchoff.swf" />
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
  <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
  <embed src="Kirchhoff.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#DDB85F" width="900" height="700" name="Kirchhoff" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" wmode="opaque" />
</body>
```